Delayed Response to an Interview Invite
I’d like to get your thoughts on this. I applied for a remote position on a job site, and a day later, I received a response with the date and time of the interview. They also mentioned that if the schedule wasn’t suitable, I should inform them to reschedule. However, in my excitement—since this is my first job interview—I missed part of their message asking me to create and send a Zoom invite before the interview. I only sent it after 11 hours. I’m now worried this might affect my chances of being accepted for the role.

We can't tell you how other people will react. But... it is very uncommon for the interviewer to ask the interviewee to create a Zoom invitation. Be wary this is a scam.

Why would 11 hours be a delayed response? For something like email this is a normal response time. How far in the future is the interview scheduled?

No worry. Just go to the interview. BTW, normally, the interviewers (or the company) send out the zoom invite to the interviewees (job applicants). It is not the other way around.

An interviewer's calender is full. They, as recruiters or in-house HR staff, spend a great deal of time interviewing candidates. This means they must have tight control of their own schedules.
Typically, they might offer several time slots for a candidate to select. But what you've written is a red-flag for several reasons.

Control of the schedule and their calendar (not in their hands)
Control of the ability to record and download the recording (not in their hands)

Without going into any futher red-flags, these alone scream "Likely Scam".
A real job offer isn't going to be lost in 11 hours.
Keep looking and good luck.

Yes, it's either a scam or a small business with a non-technical owner.
